# Home vs Component interfaces EJB

Tags: java, jpa, interface, ejb, ejb-3.0

Home Interface ([ref1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/ent21imp003.htm#BABIGDAB), [ref2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/ent21imp001.htm))

> The home interfaces are used to specify what methods a client uses to
>   create or retrieve an entity bean instance. (ref1)
>
> Requires a single create factory method, with no arguments, and a
>   single remove method.(ref2)

Component Interface ([ref1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/ent21imp004.htm#BABHHIFI), [ref2](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16439_01/doc.1013/e13981/ent21imp001.htm))

> The component interfaces define the business methods of the bean that
>   a client can invoke.(ref1)
>
> It defines the business logic methods, which are implemented in the
>   bean implementation.(ref2)

So what I understand is

You can get an instance of **ONLY** Entity Beans using Home interface, where as you can access the business methods of **ANY** Bean using Component interface. Am I right here ?

And also if I miss any difference then please elaborate other differences too. I am bit of confuse here ...

My **other** question is that in EJB3 Entity Beans are depreciated(and moved to JPA) so is there any need of HomeInterfaces in EJB3? If yes then why ? If no then how this(HomeInterface's work in EJB 2) is DONE in EJB 3 ??

Answer (score 1):

1. In EJB 2.x, Home interface allows to create an instance of an EJB. The Component interface are the actual business methods.
2. AFAIK they are not required.

Answer (score 0):

> You can get an instance of ONLY Entity Beans using Home interface,
>   where as you can access the business methods of ANY Bean using
>   Component interface. Am I right here ?

I'm not sure what point you're emphasizing here, so I'll make some statements:

All bean types (except singleton, new in EJB 3.1) support home interfaces for accessing beans.  You lookup (or inject as of EJB 3) the home interface, then you can either create a reference to an identity, or for entity beans you can find existing bean instances, or again for entities you can declare your own custom home methods that are not specific to any entity bean identity.

For stateless, there is client-visible distinct identity, so each call to create() will return an interchangeable reference.  For stateful, each call to create() returns a reference to a distinct stateful identity, which must be explicitly remove()'ed when done to minimize leaks (the container will cleanup when done).  For entity, each call to create() will return a reference to a distinct database row, and finder methods will return references to those rows.

> My other question is that in EJB3 Entity Beans are depreciated(and
>   moved to JPA) so is there any need of HomeInterfaces in EJB3? If yes
>   then why ? If no then how this(HomeInterface's work in EJB 2) is DONE
>   in EJB 3 ??

Since references to stateless and singleton are not distinct to a client, homes are far less useful since you can look them up once and cache the reference in an instance variable.  For stateful, the non-home mechanism for creating an instance is to look it up from JNDI, so there is a (minor?) performance hit for not using a home interface.

Additionally, for remote EJBHome, the getEJBMetaData method is useful for EJB frameworks that want to be able to generically handle any kind of EJB.